# How to solve inequality using mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, inequality

I've been working on my homework for hours now and am completely stumped with how to do this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

> Prove the following inequalities. Let $f$ be function that is continuous on $[a, b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$. If for some numbers $m, M,$
>
> $$m \leq f'(x) \leq M$$
>
> for all $x$ in $(a, b)$ then
>
> $$m(b − a) \leq f(b) − f(a) \leq M(b − a).$$

**My rough work so far:**

$$m(b − a) \leq f(b) − f(a) \leq M(b − a)$$

$$\displaystyle\int_a^b m \, dx \leq \displaystyle\int_a^b f(x) \, dx \leq \displaystyle\int_a^b M \, dx$$

And because $\displaystyle \displaystyle\int_a^b f'(x) \, dx = f(b) - f(a)$, $$m \leq \frac{\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x) \, dx}{b - a} \leq M$$

Since $f(x)$ is continuous by the intermediate value theorem, it takes every possible value between $m$ and $M$. Then, there is at least one value of $c$ at which $f(c)$ has the value equals to $\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x) \, dx}{b - a}$.

$$m \leq f'(x) \leq M, m(b - a) \leq f(b) - f(a) \leq M(b - a)$$

By the mean value theorem, there exists $c \in (a, b)$ such that $$m \leq f'(x) \leq M$$

where $f'(x) = \dfrac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}$. Multiplying $(b - a)$ on both sides gives us $$m(b - a) \leq f(x) \leq M(b - a)$$

Comment: Shouldn't that be $m\leq f'(x)\leq M$?

Comment: yes it should be sorry!

Comment: What have your tried so far, and where did that fail?

Comment: I just provided a link to my rough work so far

Answer (score 1):

More directly,
$f(b)-f(a)
=\int_a^b f'(x) dx
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
f(b)-f(a)-M(b-a)
&=\int_a^b f'(x) dx-M(b-a)\\
&=\int_a^b f'(x) dx-\int_a^b Mdx\\
&=\int_a^b (f'(x)-M) dx\\
&\le 0
\qquad\text{since } f'(x) \le M\\
\text{and}\\
f(b)-f(a)-m(b-a)
&=\int_a^b (f'(x)-m) dx\\
&\ge 0
\qquad\text{since } f'(x) \ge m\\
\end{array}
$

And this, of course,
is how the mean value theorem is proved.

If 
$g(x) 
= f(b)-f(a)-x(b-a)
$,
then $g(m) \ge 0$ and
$g(M) \le 0$
so that,
if $g(x)$ is continuous,
there is an $x$
in $[m, M]$ such that
$g(x) = 0$.

Comment: This uses the fundamental theorem of calculus, which, in my opinion, is not necessarily more elementary than the mean value theorem

Comment: But it is fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* You want to use the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

you don't even need to integrate.
just see $\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{b-a}=f'(c)$. with $c\in (a,b)$. (Using mean value theorem).
 But you have $m\leq f'(c)\leq M\implies m\leq \frac{f(a)-f(b)}{b-a}\leq M $

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$, the Mean-Value Theorem states there exists $c \in (a, b)$ such that $f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}$.